# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException in Apache Flink keyBy function

Tags: java, stream, apache-flink

Getting `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException` in Apache Flink. I have tried to follow the  example at [here](http://flink.apache.org/news/2016/04/06/cep-monitoring.html), however I get mentioned exemption. I have a snippet of my main class below. I will appreciate any pointer on what I have done wrong or how to troubleshoot the error.

```
DataStream<CSBEvent> inputEventStream = env.addSource(
                new FlinkKafkaConsumer09<CSBEvent>("tester03", new EventDeserializationSchema(), properties));

 Pattern<CSBEvent, ?> warningPattern = Pattern.<CSBEvent>begin("first")
                .subtype(CSBEvent.class)
                .where(evt -> evt.getEvent().getStatus().equals("FAILED"))
                .next("second")
                .subtype(CSBEvent.class)
                .where(evt -> evt.getEvent().getStatus().equals("FAILED"))
                .within(Time.seconds(10));

        // Create a pattern stream from our warning pattern
        PatternStream<CSBEvent> tempPatternStream = CEP.pattern(inputEventStream.keyBy("userID"), warningPattern); //   .pattern(

        // Generate temperature warnings for each matched warning pattern
        DataStream<CSBEvent> warnings = tempPatternStream.select(
            (Map<String, CSBEvent> pattern) -> {
                CSBEvent first = (CSBEvent) pattern.get("first");
                CSBEvent second = (CSBEvent) pattern.get("second");

                return new CSBEvent(second.getUserID());
            }
        );

        // Alert pattern: Two consecutive request failure warnings appearing within a time interval of 20 seconds
        Pattern<CSBEvent, ?> alertPattern = Pattern.<CSBEvent>begin("first")
                .next("second")
                .within(Time.seconds(20));

        // Create a pattern stream from our alert pattern
        PatternStream<CSBEvent> alertPatternStream = CEP.pattern(
                warnings.keyBy("userID"),
                alertPattern);
```

.... here is the stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.PojoTypeInfo.getTypeAt(PojoTypeInfo.java:259)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.util.keys.KeySelectorUtil.getSelectorForKeys(KeySelectorUtil.java:62)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream.keyBy(DataStream.java:276)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream.keyBy(DataStream.java:272)
at de.cep.CorrelatorVersion101.main(CorrelatorVersion101.java:61)
```

Answer (score 0):

From you code it looks like you are using Flink 1.2 right? Have you considered updating to a newer version? Currently we are close to releasing Flink 1.4.

In addition, can you post the whole stack trace to see where the exception is thrown?

Comment: i actually used Flink 1.0 as in the tutorial post, still a newbie in stream processing world. However, I will upgrade as suggested. I guess updating the version in the pom file will suffice ? My Flink installation is version 1.3.2 though. I have updated with complete stacktrace.

Comment: If your installation is Flink 1.3.2 as you mentioned, and your code is built against Flink 1.0, then you will very likely have problems. Backwards compatibility has been broken between Flink 1.3 and versions before 1.1.